# NHibernate transaction management if session is closed

Tags: nhibernate, transactions

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate, but I looked around a bit and couldn't find this question.

Let's say I have an NHibernate session and within it, I have a transaction.  If I close the session, is it safe to assume that the transaction get committed/rolled back (depending on specifics of what's going on in transaction)?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your session being closed by the same thread that executed a commit or rollback?

Comment: While it would all be the same thread, I guess what I'm asking is what happens if I close the session without doing anything to the transaction besides initially creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [NHForge.org](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/09/08/part-9-nhibernate-transactions.aspx):

> The ITransaction will perform an implicit rollback when it is
>   disposed, unless an explicit call to Commit or Rollback has already
>   occurred. This implicit rollback can indicate a missing call to
>   Commit, so it [generates an alert in NHibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/AvoidImplicitRollback). If you
>   intend to rollback, do it explicitly. Your code will be easier to
>   understand.

Comment: Just to clarify, if I'm disposing my session, then the transaction gets rolled back and then disposed, and only then the session gets disposed.  Is that correct?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if you create a session and a transaction within that session, the changes you make (if any) would not affect the underlying database unless a commit is issued. Otherwise, the transaction is rolled back. From what I understood from your case, you are not issuing a commit, so your transaction would be rolled back.